# ros_canopen Profile position + Interpolated position modes

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm working on a custom made robotic arm actuated by different motion controllers/motors via `ros_canopen`.
Currently, the motors are controlled in `profile position mode` defined in the relevant `yaml` config file as follows:

```
robot_5s_arm_joint_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5

  required_drive_mode: 1
```

Due to some mechanical issues, i need to change the `required_drive_mode` **to** `Interpolated position mode`, but **only three controllers** (joint1-3) **support this mode**, the rest (joint4-5) can only be driven in profile position mode.

So the question is, what is the workaround here? :)

I suppose, that two arm_joint_controller groups shall be defined, one (joint1-3) with `required_drive_mode: 7` and the other with `required_drive_mode: 1`. Then simply, in the `moveit` controller `yaml` file, i can define these controllers? Is this enough?

Do i need to change the planning group defined in `moveit`?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331114/ros_canopen-profile-position-+-interpolated-position-modes/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So the question is, what is the workaround here? :)

You can specify mixed modes

> I suppose, that two arm_joint_controller groups shall be defined, one (joint1-3) with required_drive_mode: 7 and the other with required_drive_mode: 1

Much simpler: you can define a default mode (`required_drive_mode`, singular) and add a look-up (`required_drive_modes`, plural) for the others:

```
robot_5s_arm_joint_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
  
  required_drive_mode: 7
  required_drive_modes:
    joint_4: 1
    joint_5: 1
```

or you set all explicitly:

```
robot_5s_arm_joint_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
  
  required_drive_modes:
    joint_1: 7
    joint_2: 7
    joint_3: 7
    joint_4: 1
    joint_5: 1
```

> Then simply, in the moveit controller yaml file, i can define these controllers? Is this enough?

Not needed.

> Do i need to change the planning group defined in moveit?

Nope :)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-08-20**:
wow! THANKS!!!